# Assignement to optional unimplemented field

Tags: typescript

Assume we have interface:

```
interface ICustom
{
    value?:boolean;
}
```

and implement it without optional field or function:

```
class Custom implements ICustom 
{
}
```

try to get or set value:

```
var v:Custom = new Custom();
v.value = true; //TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Custom'.
```

Why i need this. My idea is to create mixin decorator (already done) and use interfaces instead of concrete classes to avoid code duplication:

```
@mixin([Custom])
class Customizable implements ICustom
{}
```

Well, at least i can do the following:

```
var c: ICustom = new Customizable();
```

Update:

Perhaps it will be possible in 2.0:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8625

Comment: Well, can you just make it a class instead of the interface then? Inheriting members is one reason for inheriting classes that in fact prevents code duplication.

Comment: Is there any way to implement(not extend) class without implementing all its variables and methods? Currently compiler complains that `value:boolean` is not implemented.

Comment: And why can't you extend it?

Comment: multiple mixins could be applied see [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Mixins.md)

Comment: Ah I see, so that's the TS limitation. Apparently the link you provided requires you to do that.

Comment: given that both Custom and Customizable implement ICustom, couldn't you just make Custom implements ICustom und Customizable extends Custom? If you don't need much more than these 3 classes I think you are complicating it with the mixes

Comment: Could you clarify what it is you're trying to accomplish or what your question is?